# Setting Div (#Map) height and width to 100%

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, esri

I'm setting 100% width and height to the div (map), but my map shows only half of the page. I would like to display the full map below the div container.

I am using bootstrap and esri JavaScript api to build the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7, IE=9, IE=10">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
<title>Simple Map</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/js/esri/css/esri.css">
<script>
  dojo.require("esri.map");

  function init() {
    var map = new esri.Map("map",{
      basemap:"topo",
      center:[-95.45,29.80], //long, lat
      zoom:10,
      sliderStyle:"small"

    });
  }
  dojo.ready(init);
</script>
 <style>
  #map {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body class="claro">
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Project Name</a>
      </div><!-- /.container -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
    <div id="map" class="claro"></div>
  </div><!-- /.navbar -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this (to your external css file or inline `style` tag):

```
html body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Could be worth stating where that code should be added, even if it's obvious to you!

Answer (score 1):

At bootstrap 3.0 twitter bootstrap adds a .container css class which overrides the map container. The result is that a max-width is set on the .map .container. Add this to override and make the map fill the complete width:

```
html body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.map .container{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
#map{height:100%; min-height:100%;}
```